# How to get all parameters in MSSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, asp-classic

When I was using asp, I was able to do the following - now I am using php and sqlsrv - how do I achieve the same in php

```
    Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
oCmd.CommandText =  "dbo.spGetItem"
oCmd.CommandType = &H0004 'adCmdStoredProc
oCmd.Parameters.Refresh

For Each prmTemp In oCmd.Parameters
        Response.Write( prmTemp.direction & "<br/>" & prmTemp.name)
Next

Set oCmd = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ORDINAL_POSITION, PARAMETER_NAME, DATA_TYPE, PARAMETER_MODE  from information_schema.parameters
where specific_name='Proc_Name'
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx

Comment: Much appreciate its a very good read very informative :) im off from here now gonna read it from start to end :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way regardless of client language is to just query the metadata / catalog views:

```
SELECT name, is_output 
  FROM sys.parameters 
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.spGetItem');
```

Comment: yeap, php mssql extension doesn't provide meta info via specific functions